# Using xxd in Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, xxd

I installed gvim82 to specifically use the `xxd` command in windows. I ran the `:!xxd -i` command followed by `file_name.txt > header_file_name.h` in the windows command prompt but nothing happens, not even throwing any errors. Can someone help?  Is  `:!xxd` only used in the Vim environment?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The `:!` part is pretty much exclusive to Vim, since it's Vim syntax to run an external shell command. Can you just run `xxd` directly? As in: `C:\>xxd -i file_name.txt > header_file_name.h` ?

Comment: On Windows it doesn't recognize xxd. Are there any similar commands that I can use on windows? I specifically want to make a header file with the data in the text file which xxd on linux does that

Comment: Which directory did you install Vim to? Something like `C:\Program Files\Vim\Vim8.2` or similar? Can you find an `xxd.exe` in there? Does it help if you add that directory to `%PATH%` or call `xxd` using the full path?

Comment: windows command prompt is not POSIX sh (from where the `>` redirect syntax originates). I have no idea if that will work there. And @filbranden is right; `:!` is a vim command.

Comment: @filbranden It worked!! Thanks! So I should add the xxd patch into my script every time I want to use it? is it the only way? Because I ran the command in the Vim folder which I know is not a good idea